# jQuery - :nth-child() or eq() pattern possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to select 1st, 4th, 7th, 10th, 13th, 16th etc

http://jsfiddle.net/caRxA/

Comment: Googling "jQuery nth-child" brings up http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/ what you want to do should be possible by using a combination.

Comment: I was tripping up on where it started counting from, I was using :nth-child(4+1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sure `:nth-child(3n+1)` will do.

Comment: I think it should be "3n-2"; the "n" values start at 1, not zero. Thus "3n+1" would skip the 1st one.

Comment: @Pointy, that doesn't *seem* to be a problem: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/HR7QN/)

Comment: oh you're probably right - it doesn't work the way I was thinking

Comment: @Yammi, not in Chromium 10 and Firefox 4 (both on Ubuntu 10.10), the sequence is: 1,4,7,10,13,16,19, 22, 25, 28, 31...

Comment: Yeah, face palm, my jsfiddle missed out a number in the sequence so it was always skipping one

Answer (score 1):

As Pekka noted from the jQuery documentation.

You can call [`:nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) with an expression in terms of `n`.

```
$('.my-set:nth-child(3n+1)');
```